# Sending and Retrieving AmpScript Values in Email strings for Microsites

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, subscriber-key

We're using personalization strings in the url for the Unsubscribe links in our emails. The url links to our Preference Center microsite and includes certain values such as `Job ID`, `List ID`, `MemberID`, etc. We also want to add the Subscriber Key to the string but I'm not quite understanding the necessary syntax because I seem to be able to get a value for it.

Here's an example of the string are are using: https://our.microsite.com/preference/?emailaddress=%%emailaddr%%&s=%%ex2;subscriberid%%&j=%%ex2;jobid%%&mid=%%ex2;MemberID%%&l=%%ex2;listid%%&jb=%%ex2;_JobSubscriberBatchID%%&ju=%%ex2;joburlid%%&sk=%%_subscriberkey%%

Here is the code for creating the variables from the :

```
Set @emailAddress = [emailaddr]

Set @subKey = [_subscriberkey]
Set @jobID = [JobID]
Set @listID = [ListID]
Set @batchID = [_JobSubscriberBatchID]
Set @subscriberID = [subscriberid]
Set @accountMID = [MemberID]
```

After creating variables for the strings I get the following values:

```
@subKey = , @accountMID = ##########, @emailAddress = mySampleEmailAddress@gmail.com
```

Any ideas on why there's no value for the subscriber key? Is it the syntax in the the personalization string?

Comment: Can you show your outputs - ensure the output for `@subkey` is correct (`%%=v(@subkey)=%%`). The correct personalization string IS being used to set it: `_subscriberkey`, so it is not likely to be that.  I would also check to see if `@subkey` is being set anywhere else that could potentially be overwriting it prior to output.

Comment: Thanks foryour input. I did try (have been trying to)  output the subscriber key as you suggested but it doesn't seem to have a value. Additionally I looked to see if it was being overwritten somehow but I don't see any indications of that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) function in an email to pass information via a URL in an encrypted query string:

e.g.

`<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL('pageID','parameter1','value1','parameter2', value2))=%%">`

The above will pass along 'parameter1' & 'parameter2' (just examples and more parameters can be passed along too) but also default send string values also get passed through the link query too. A list can be found here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5

As you'll see subscriber Key is one of them: `%%_subscriberkey%%`

So in your microsite code, you can assign the subscriber key to a variable, without having to directly pick it up using the `QueryParameter()` Ampscript function.

e.g.

`set @subId = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need [] for the `_subscriberkey` you can just use the vairable as you will have reference to the email send when you use [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm)

```
Set @subKey = _subscriberkey
```

Comment: FYI,  I'm new to SF and MC and am picking up on an existing project. But since the microsite is built in classic content, would your answer still apply?

Comment: Honestly I'm not 100% sure as I only have limited experience writing cloud pages using content builder , but its worth giving a shot!

Comment: @C-angell use like this set @subkey=AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")

Comment: @C-angell - As pkharries said in his comment, you will want to use the AttributeValue() function. It has much better null and error handling than using the raw personalization string.

Comment: @pkharries, I'm not able to get this @subkey=AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")  to work but I'm wondering if that's because the url personalization string has not  been setup incorrectly. That's assuming the AttributeValue function pulls the subscriberkey from the url. I think the SF support person added **sk=%%subscriberkey%%** to the url rather than **sk=%%_subscriberkey%%**. Also I'm not sure we're using **sk=%%_subscriberkey%%** in the string as opposed to  **%%_subscriberkey%%**. I've been looking for useful examples of url personalization strings but haven't found much.

Comment: I was finally able to pull in the subscriber key from the url string by using the following: Set  `@subKey = RequestParameter("sk")`. Where in the url "sk"is set to equal the subsciberkey -  sk=%%_subscriberkey%%. Not sure why Set `@subKey = AttributeValue("sk")` wouldn't work.

Comment: @C-angell how are you calling the micro site from the email?

Comment: @codeinthecloud  - using an encrypted url in the unsubscribe link